# https SSL for IP address?

Tags: ios, node.js, http, ssl, ubuntu-16.04

I have HTTP requests in my iOS app to a simple NODE.js app on my server. Since iOS has App Transport Security, I wondered how I could simply add a self-signed SSL certification to my IP address then I wouldn't have to worry about bypassing ATS. It would just look like

```
https://192.0.2.12/API
```

Is there a simple way to do it on an Ubuntu server?

Comment: No, because you would need an X509 certificate with an IP and not a name, which will be complicated (technically possible in some cases, but not for HTTPS like that).

Comment: Just set up a host name and get a cert from let’s encrypt.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: What makes it complicated? I've done it with openssl and it's very easy.

Comment: @JamesKPolk like I said technically, everything is possible, yes, you can choose what you put in a certificate, however having IPs there instead of names is certainly not the usual case for HTTPS (and many other protocols) and will certainly not work out of the box with usual tools (and if the OP asks for this I have to believe that he is surely not mastering `openssl` as well as you do). For examples passing the CAB Forum requirements... No SNI, etc... So I prefer to deter people from trying that and instead go back to the usual case of using hostnames, as I think it is a more sound advice.

Comment: (And I am not even sure that it would be acceptable to do that in a smartphone application, it could as well be detected and be a motive to refuse listing on the store; for example https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33 only speaks about adding exceptions for some given "domain names", never speaks about IP addresses)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek: Yes, agreed. I'm not aware of any reason to connect to a bare IP address and many reasons not to, including that no CA will offer a certificate for an IP address.

Comment: @JamesKPolk certificates with bare IP addresses are used in RPKI, but this is a far distant world from the HTTPS world, and there the CAs are the RIRs.